# Combine JSON "rows" into new object with "colums"

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object array that looks something like this

```
 [
    {"PM":"Jane","e":"j@nunya.com","h":"15.00","w":"10/30/2016 12:00:00 AM","c":"John","p":"Happy Town USA"},
    {"PM":"Jane","e":"j@nunya.com","h":"11.00","w":"11/06/2016 12:00:00 AM","c":"John","p":"Happy Town USA"},
    {"PM":"Jill","e":"j@nunya.com","h":"21.00","w":"10/30/2016 12:00:00 AM","c":"John","p":"Sad Town USA"},
    {"PM":"Jill","e":"j@nunya.com","h":"12.00","w":"11/06/2016 12:00:00 AM","c":"John","p":"Sad Town USA"}
 ]
```

Looking at the data all "columns" for a given PM,e, p, c combination the data is same except the w and the h fields. I need to transform this data into a new object that would look something like this.

```
[
    {PM:"Jane",e:"j@nunya.com",c:"John",p:"Happy Town USA",
     Details:[{"w":"10/30/2016","h":"15.00"},{"w":"11/06/2016","h":"11.00"}]},
    {PM:"Jill",e:"j@nunya.com",c:"John",p:"Sad Town USA",
    Details:[{"w":"10/30/2016","h":"21.00"},{"w":"11/06/2016","h":"12.00"}]}
]
```

It's kind of like making columns from rows in a SQL query, unfortunately I have little control over the source data so that is not an option.

Comment: I can suggest in 2 ways you can achive your goal. One - Programaticaly do the transformation , Two : Convert the JSON to XML and use XSLT to do the transformation and convert the result xml into JSON. First approach would be simple but second approach would be robus as you are externalizing transformation logic to XSLT. APIs are available to convert JSON to XML and viseversa.

Comment: How to do that exactly depends on which language you are using to process JSON. You cannot to such a transformation with JSON itself (because it is not a programming language)

Comment: I should have mentioned the language, it's Javascript, both sound interesting.

Comment: So your question actually hasn't to do anything with JSON. You are asking how to group objects in JavaScript.

Comment: It has a lot to do with JSON... I need the resulting object in JSON format. Language is not super important... If I could do it in one I could probably do it in another.

Comment: JSON isn't a language. It isn't an object either. It's a string. You need to convert your original JSON *string* to an object, manipulate that object, and then convert you object back to a JSON *string*. So since converting to and from JSON is trivial in javascript (`JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`), the question really is about manipulating javascript objects

Comment: @user1735894 JSON is a *string*. You are talking about JavaScript objects. Your question has nothing to do with JSON, even if you got that datastructure by calling `JSON.parse` on a JSON string and/or intend to `JSON.stringify` it afterwards.

Comment: Fair enough, it's not a language or an object. I did state that I was using Javascript to try to make this transformation. Any chance someone could offer a solution in Javascript on how to transform this string into the desired format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var source = [{
  "PM": "Jane",
  "e": "j@nunya.com",
  "h": "15.00",
  "w": "10/30/2016 12:00:00 AM",
  "c": "John",
  "p": "Happy Town USA"
}, {
  "PM": "Jane",
  "e": "j@nunya.com",
  "h": "11.00",
  "w": "11/06/2016 12:00:00 AM",
  "c": "John",
  "p": "Happy Town USA"
}, {
  "PM": "Jill",
  "e": "j@nunya.com",
  "h": "21.00",
  "w": "10/30/2016 12:00:00 AM",
  "c": "John",
  "p": "Sad Town USA"
}, {
  "PM": "Jill",
  "e": "j@nunya.com",
  "h": "12.00",
  "w": "11/06/2016 12:00:00 AM",
  "c": "John",
  "p": "Sad Town USA"
}];

// First we'll transform the source into a dictionary
var dict = source.reduce(function(p, c) {
  // We'll use the combination of PM,e,c and p to build a key
  var key = [c.PM, c.e, c.c, c.p].join("-");
  if (p[key]) {
    // If we've seen this key before, we'll just add to the Details
    p[key].Details.push({
      w: c.w,
      h: c.h
    });
  } else {
    // otherwise we create a new entry and populate it
    p[key] = {
      PM: c.PM,
      c: c.c,
      e: c.e,
      p: c.p,
      Details: [{
        w: c.w,
        h: c.h
      }]
    }
  }
  return p;
}, {});

// We now have a dictionary
console.log(dict);

// If you really need an array (and don't care about order), we can transform
// the dictonary to an array (order is not guaranteed here)
var result = Object.keys(dict).map(function(a) {
  return dict[a];
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfect and is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `reduce` to accomplish these kinds of transformations in JavaScript:

```
var arr = /* your array of objects goes here */;

var results = Object.values(arr.reduce(function(obj, row) {
  var pm = row.PM;

  // here we check to see if we already have an aggregator for that pm
  if (!obj[pm]) {
    obj[pm] = {
      PM: pm,
      e: row.e,
      c: row.c,
      p: row.p
      Details: []
    };
  }

  // now we need to add a record to the Details
  obj[pm].Details.push({ w: row.w, h: row.h });

  // common mistake using reduce is to forget 
  // to return the accumulator
  return obj;
}, {}));
```

You can convert back to a JSON string with `JSON.stringify`. Note that `Object.values` is not yet implemented in every JavaScript environment, you may need to polyfill it.

Answer (score 0):

Java approach only: This question sounds very challenging for a quick solution. I got a partial solution here using Java Oson library I created, here is [the source file](https://github.com/osonus/oson/blob/master/src/test/java/ca/oson/json/merge/MergeTest.java):

```
@Test
public void testTableMerge2() {
    List<Map> list = oson.readValue("rows2Columns.txt");

    Map<String, List> collected = new HashMap<>();

    for (Map map: list) {
        String key = (String) map.get("PM");
        List obj = collected.get(key);

        if (obj == null) {
            obj = new ArrayList();

            collected.put(key, obj);
        }

        obj.add(map);
    }

    Config config = merge.getConfig();
    config.numericValue = NUMERIC_VALUE.MERGE_UNIQUE;
    config.nonnumericalValue = NONNUMERICAL_VALUE.MERGE_UNIQUE;
    config.listValue = LIST_VALUE.MERGE_UNIQUE;

    Map<String, Object> results = new HashMap<>();

    for (String key: collected.keySet()) {
        results.put(key, merge.merge(collected.get(key)));
    }

    Collection result = results.values();

    // oson.pretty();
    String json = oson.serialize(result);

    String expected = "[{\"PM\":\"Jill\",\"e\":\"j@nunya.com\",\"h\":[\"21.00\",\"12.00\"],\"w\":[\"10/30/2016 12:00:00 AM\",\"11/06/2016 12:00:00 AM\"],\"c\":\"John\",\"p\":\"Sad Town USA\"},{\"PM\":\"Jane\",\"e\":\"j@nunya.com\",\"h\":[\"15.00\",\"11.00\"],\"w\":[\"10/30/2016 12:00:00 AM\",\"11/06/2016 12:00:00 AM\"],\"c\":\"John\",\"p\":\"Happy Town USA\"}]";

    assertEquals(expected, json);
}
```